# What can I do to set up Wireless Sync on Windows 8?

Tags: zune, wireless-sync

I have Windows 8 Consumer Preview installed, but can't seem to set Wireless Sync up.

Has this issue been resolved? Did anyone manage to get Wireless Sync working properly?

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?

Comment: Running Windows 8.1 instead of Windows 7 since recently; but I haven't tried setting up Wireless Sync, as a result of never having it I sync quite infrequently.

Answer (score 2):

If you get the error `80004001` it means (in developer terms) that it is not implemented (yet). And more importantly, anything can change without notice on a beta (preview) release.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to copy the relevant components from Windows 7, perhaps forcing Zune to call Windows 7 DLLs instead of the Windows 8 DLLs. Because it worked back then, but now it seems missing. I would suspect it to be not that hard to fill up a hole, if only I knew how exactly...

Comment: I wouldn't do that, since you can't be sure what you get. Keep the wireless sync on your Windows 7 PC instead.

Comment: I have no Windows 7, will wait for more response to see whether anyone else got something fixed. Or perhaps hunt for it myself one of these days...